# How to block access in OnAuthorizationAsync()

Tags: c#, asp.net-authorization

I am implementing a custom authorization system and I want to create an authorization filter.  To do this I implement IAsyncAuthorizationFilter interface and as far as I understand it, to block access to an Action/Controller I need to set AuthorizationFilterContext.Result to something

Comment: Yes, your understanding is correct. I'd think a `StatusCodeResult` with a relevant status code. Presumably 401 (the client didn't provide valid credentials / didn't provide credentials) or 403 (the client has credentials but can't access this resource in this way).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

By using this method, your application expects a HTTP status code as a returning value.

You can create a ***if statement*** that blocks the response if the return code is 401 (which means "Unauthorized").

**However**, there are more reasons why your response might not return. I would suggest you to create a ***switch case*** statement that could process the following codes:

1. **401** Unauthorized;
2. **403** Forbidden;
3. **407** Proxy Authentication Required.

Comment: You seem to be approaching this from the perspective of a client receiving such a status code. OP is talking about the server implementation.

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar This codes are also used between server messaging comms.

But we should use class StatusCodeResult, as you replied, instead of the raw code digits.

Comment: I mean your answer talks about how to handle this on the client side. You should edit your answer to demonstrate how to send such a status code as a response from the server in `AuthorizationFilterContext`